# Converting "ADD_MONTH" from oracle (SQL - TOAD) to ODBC ANSI

Tags: sql, oracle, odbc

We are converting from SQL (ORACLE) to ansi (ODBC) and i am having trouble converting this statement. Not sure how the ADD_MONTHS statement works (ansi). Look under the where statement. The statement works fine in ORACLE it only pulls last months end of month (Financial month 22 of the month before to the 21st of the current month)

Query below. I hope someone can help :)

```
SELECT 
PRIN, 
SUB_PAJ, 
ID_PAJ, 
CDE_PAJ, 
RSN_PAJ, 
NO_PAJ, 
OLD_PAJ, 
RESOL_DTE_PAJ

FROM data.PAJ_DATA

WHERE RESOL_DTE_PAJ BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('22-' || TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'MON')||'-'|| TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY'),-1) 
AND ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('21-'||TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'MON')||'-'|| TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'YYYY'),'DD-MM-YYYY'),0)
```

Comment: The second `add_months` makes no sense, as it is adding 0 months.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions011.htm

Comment: In ANSI SQL `add_month()` would be something like: `current_date + interval '1' month'`. Not sure what you mean with ANSI ODBC though.

Comment: The link and your comments were very helpful. Thanks alot! :)